# Avoid opening closed cell group after button click

Tags: notebooks, cells

```
Button["Hello", Print["Hello"]]
```

---

Opened cell group:

[image]

Closed cell group (input cell is hidden by double-clicking output cell):

[image]

But then if I click the button the group cell opens.

How to avoid this opening?

Answer (score 0):

In v13.3.1 on macOS 14.3, closing the input cell from the Cell menu, or deleting the input cell both work. When I close the input cell with your method of double-clicking the output cell, the input cell does not reopen, but all of the printed output remains hidden in the closed composite cell.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code for interactive hiding of the code for interfaces:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> Dynamic@f];
Dynamic@Button["Hello", Print["Hello"]]
```

Setting later `f=False` leads to hiding of the code without any inconveniences with output. Actually, one can remove `Dynamic` wrapping the `Button` without lose of the functionality.

[image]